# Jquery ui widget copy in ie7 and ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I run into a strange behavior on jquery ui (tested on jquery 1.8.3, jquery-ui 1.9.2).

I have a parent and child widget, on the _create method of the parent I give the parent's self reference to the newly created child.
When I try to access this reference from within the child all the function and properties declared after the building of the child are not available.

```
(function ($) {
  $.widget("ui.parentWidget", $.ui.mouse, {
    version: "@VERSION", widgetEventPrefix: "parentWidget",

_create: function () {
  var self = this;
  self.child = $("<div/>")
    .childWidget({ parent: self })
    .appendTo(self.element);
  self.parentName = "parent";
},

parentFeature: function() {
    return "feature";
},

getChild: function() {
    return this.child;
},

updateChild: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.child.childWidget("update", self);
}
});}(jQuery));
```

The child widget

```
(function ($) {
$.widget("ui.childWidget", $.ui.mouse, {
    version: "@VERSION", widgetEventPrefix: "childWidget",

    options: {
    },

    _create: function () {
    },

    childParent: function () {
        return this.options.parent;
    },

    updatedParent: function() {
        return this.newParent;
    },

    update: function(parent) {
        var self = this;
        self.newParent = parent;
    }
});
}(jQuery));
```

Now to test my output I just create a parent, retrieve its child, and read the child's parents from the child and display the results.

```
var parent = $("<div/>").parentWidget();
parent.parentWidget("updateChild");
var child = parent.parentWidget("getChild");
var childParent = child.childWidget("childParent");
var updatedParent = child.childWidget("updatedParent");
```

`childParent.parentName` or `childParent.parentFeature()` are `undefined` on ie7 and ie8 and works fine everywhere else `updatedParent` possesses all its content.

My question being, is this a bug ? or did I misunderstood how to properly use jquery ui plugin.